# Что будет если отключить RTTI

Tags: c++

Я использую LLVM RTTI, поэтому отключил стандартный RTTI в студии (/GR-).

У меня несколько вопросов:

- **Если отключить RTTI, влияет ли это на стандартные библиотеки или внешние библиотеки (GTest например)? Может ли что-то сломаться?**
- **Если отключить RTTI, отключается ли он для .h фалов?**

Например в Foo.h написаны шаблоны, которые унаследованы от базового класса, их нельзя перенести в .cpp, т.к. это шаблоны.

```
class Base {};

template<class T>
struct foo : Base {};

template<class T>
struct boo : Base {};
```

- **Если отключить RTTI, перестают ли классы хранить указатель на VTable?**

Comment: *"Может ли что-то сломаться?"* В [мануале](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/gr-enable-run-time-type-information?view=msvc-170) вроде нормально описано. RTTI != vtables, виртуальные функции все равно работают. Отлетит то, что использует `dynamic_cast` (возможно не во всех случаях) и `typeid`, в том числе в стандартной библиотеке. *"отключается ли он для .h файлов"* `#include` препроцессором заменяется на содержимое хедера, поэтому очевидно да.

Comment: Вообще непонятно, чем RTTI не угодил. Если он вам не нужен, просто не используйте его. Вам правда нужен крохотный выигрыш в размере бинарника, который он дает?

Comment: Думаю, что такой выигрыш мне не нужен, оставлю как есть

Comment: @HolyBlackCat я всегда отключаю rtti, ибо его возможности не использую. Зачем нужен лишний балласт в бинарнике/памяти? Тем более, что rtti - дополнительная инфа для дизассемблерщика))) Сам, когда ковырял чужие программы, ни раз благодарил разрабов за то, что оставили rtti в коде)))